# How to add a fixed View above the Sticky Header RecyclerView in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I implemented the Sticky Header successfully with the 'Flexible Adapter', and I want to place an EditText in between Toolbar and Sticky Header. But, now the header disappearing under the EditText while scrolling. Please help me for keeping Section Headers Sticky below the EditText.....

**mylayout.xml is like this:**

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F6FAFD">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_white"
            android:text="000000"
            android:textSize="25sp"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/my_recyclerview"/>

</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />
```

**This one I want to have**

[image: My aim to get]

**But now, the Section Header goes under the EditText**
[image]

Comment: can you share your complete xml file.

Comment: @Ashish, of course. the above posted layout is started with the **FrameLayout** which can't show as I have less experience with stack overflow. And that is the full layout.xml file, excepted only the starting and ending tags of FrameLayout. Any more you want ?

Comment: @Ashish, my **recyclerview.xml** file only contains width,  height & id only. The **section_header.xml** is a LinearLayout file wich hold two TextViews only. Any more you want ?

Comment: As per my knowledge. Only one sticky header stays at top other got scrolled up. (ref. from your first image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Temporarily I got desired result by the following way. But I don't think it is a perfect way.**

Firstly I put myrecyclerViewlayout.xml & myEditText in seperate FrameLayout and programically changed the top margin of my recyclerView on fragment. Thus got suceeded.

The Code is :

**changes in layout.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/recycler_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

        <include layout="@layout/my_recyclerview"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/asset_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFEDC8">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_total_amount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:hint="Enter Total Amount"
            android:textSize="17sp"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

**code in onViewCreated of myFragment**

```
final FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_layout);
        if ((layout != null) && (savedInstanceState == null)) {
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
            params.setMargins(0,182,0,0);
            layout.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have removed your FrameLayout inside LinearLayout and added EditText directly inside LinearLayout. FrameLayout was needed there. here is my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_white"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="000000"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <include layout="@layout/my_recyclerview"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Please check and let me know does it work for you or not?

Comment: Sorry, the same problem exists with your layout.